# Is there any way to checkout the previous commit without knowing the ID?

Tags: git, version-control

If I am going to use checkout to find bugs in my code, I think it would be helpful to be able to checkout the previous commit without having to lookup its ID with `git log`. Or more efficient at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, git provides two nice ways to do this: `HEAD^` or `HEAD~1` (HEAD is your current commit). The number of carets following `HEAD` or the number after the tilda determine how many commits back you are referring to.

So for instance `HEAD^^^` or `HEAD~3` both refer to three commits back.

To checkout the previous commit, it's just

```
git checkout HEAD^
```

To checkout the previous commit relative to a specific branch's commit, say `develop`, it's just

```
git checkout develop^
```

Answer (score 0):

There are [several ways](http://schacon.github.io/gitbook/4_git_treeishes.html) to refer to commits. The full SHA is the most direct one. For your purposes, `HEAD^` should work.